# Localhost Request React Native

Tags: react-native, .net-core, fetch

I know there are so many questions and solutions here but they did not solve my problem.
I am using React Native, I tried too many solutions but It did not solve. I have an API (localhost) but I can't reach it. I tried IPv4, 10.0.2.2, Ip, etc.

```
fetch('http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/library',{
  method: 'POST',
  header: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type:': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    'usernamedata': this.state.usernameText,
    'passworddata': this.state.passwordText
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use ngrok to expose your IP:  https://ngrok.com/